# Not sure how to XPath to specific website element

Tags: python, css, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I'm currently trying to use Scrapy to go through the Elite Dangerous subreddit and collect post titles, urls, and vote counts. I did the first two fine, but am unsure of how to write an XPath expression to access the votes.

`selector.xpath('//div[@class="score unvoted"]').extract()` works, but it returns vote counts for all posts on the current page (instead of for each individual post). `response.css('div.score.unvoted').extract()` Works for each individual post, but returns `[u'<div class="score unvoted">1</div>']`, instead of just 1. ( I would also really like to know how to do this with XPath! :) )

Code is as follows:

```
class redditSpider(CrawlSpider):  # http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider
    name = "reddits"
    allowed_domains = ["reddit.com"]
    start_urls = [
    "https://www.reddit.com/r/elitedangerous",
    ]

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            allow=['/r/EliteDangerous/\?count=\d*&after=\w*']),  # Looks for next page with RE
        callback='parse_item',  # What do I do with this? --- pass to self.parse_item
        follow=True),  # Tells spider to continue after callback
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        selector_list = response.css('div.thing') # Each individual little "box" with content

        for selector in selector_list:
            item = RedditItem()
            item['title'] = selector.xpath('div/p/a/text()').extract()
            item['url'] = selector.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            # item['votes'] = selector.xpath('//div[@class="score unvoted"]')
            item['votes'] = selector.css('div.score.unvoted').extract()
            yield item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. The first approach just needs two things:

- a dot at the beginning to make it [context-specific](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths)
- `text()` at the end

Fixed version:

```
selector.xpath('.//div[@class="score unvoted"]/text()').extract()
```

And, FYI, you can make the second option work too by using the [`::text` pseudo-element](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#id1):

```
response.css('div.score.unvoted::text').extract()
```

Comment: Thank you, the context-specific dot makes everything so much easier :). Another thanks for the ::text pseudo-element.

Answer (score 0):

this should work -

```
selector.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "score unvoted")]/text()').extract()
```

Comment: Same issue, returns votes for the entire page rather than just votes under the current div.

Comment: selector.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "score unvoted")]/text()')[0].extract()